# Can I use my own website as an example?

Tags: support, questions

If I have a certain bug on my website, can i link it in my question so that people can see what I am referring to more easily?

Comment: TL;DR You can include a link as an additional resource, but you should still provide a minimal example that reproduces the bug directly in your question; either as code or as a stack snippet. An external link should always be a supplement to the post, a question that just says "hey guys this page [link] has a bug that causes [...], how do I solve that" will be closed.

Comment: Once the issue is solved, the question becomes invalid.  Others who have similar problems get no use from your question.  That goes against the ethos of StackOverflow--we're helping everyone, not just you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few people want to go to another website to help your troubleshoot.  I think of providing a link to your source code and asking people to download it to help you demonstrate the problem.

One of the guidelines for asking a good question is to [provide a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is a **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample.  You should not provide a link and ask "find my bug".  Rather, you should work to create a new example in which you can provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the bug in as few lines of code as possible.

This process is key to any kind of troubleshooting that you do, not just for asking a question on Stack Overflow.  Once you start removing code irrelevant to the problem, you may find the source of the problem on your own.

Now once you create your MCVE and you write out your question, you are certainly welcome to provide a link (and/or screenshot) to show the issue as a secondary means of communicating the problem, but the link should **never** be the only demonstration of the problem.

Besides simplifying the problem to the core issue, one of the key reasons that we ask this of questions askers is for longevity.  While you see your question solving **your** problem, we see your question as solving **everyone's** problem who has the same issue as yours.  Someone in the future may find your question via google, and we don't want them to have to keep following links to your site to confirm it is the same exact bug.  Once you fix your bug, your question will be meaningless to anyone else because they can't see what the bug is.  And if the link to your website breaks, then no one can get there either.

Comment: And a link shouldn't be to something that can change and render the link useless. So linking to a site is (by its very nature) a bad idea.